# QGIS 2.10 crashes while working with Qgis2web plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, qgis-2.10, qgis2web

Currently I am working on Qgis2Web for editing and generating web maps from my vector data. But after opening the plug in window. QGIS got crashed.

[image]

Comment: I don't have QGIS 2.10 to test this but you could delete the Qgis2web plugin folder. If you're on Windows, it should be located in _C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins\Qgis2web_. When deleted, you should be able to load QGIS again and perhaps try reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: I tried for your suggestion but sorry it didn't help that much still getting same error. i attached error snapshot in my question hope you will get some idea. I am in beginner stage of using QGIS. so your help is valuable for me

Comment: Does this happen with a specific project or independent of what data is loaded?

Comment: No remaining all project working very finely. getting crashed error to particular project.

Comment: Which version of qgis2web are you using? Better exception handling was added in recent versions.